# Sequential k-means clustering using scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, scikit-learn

Is there a way to perform sequential k-means clustering using scikit-learn? I can't seem to find a proper way to add new data, without re-fitting all the data.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

scikit-learn's `KMeans` class has a [`predict`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.predict) method that, given some (new) points, determines which of the clusters these points would belong to. Calling this method does *not* change the cluster centroids.

If you *do* want the centroids to be changed by the addition of new data, i.e. you want to do clustering in an online setting, use the [`MiniBatchKMeans`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#mini-batch-kmeans) estimator and its `partial_fit` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass in initial values for the centroids with the `init` parameter to [`sklearn.cluster.kmeans`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.k_means.html). So then you can just do:

```
centroids, labels, inertia = k_means(data, k)
new_data = np.append(data, extra_pts)
new_centroids, new_labels, new_inertia = k_means(new_data, k, init=centroids)
```

assuming you're just adding data points and not changing `k`.

I think this will sometimes mean you get a suboptimal result, but it should usually be faster. You might want to occasionally redo the fit with, say, 10 random seeds and take the best one.

Answer (score 1):

It's also relatively easy to write your own function that finds out which centroid is closest to a point that you are considering. Assuming you have some matrix `X` that is ready for kmeans:

```
centroids, labels, inertia = cluster.k_means(X, 5)

def pred(arr):
    return np.argmin([np.linalg.norm(arr-b) for b in centroids])
```

You can confirm that this works via:

```
[pred(X[i]) == labels[i] for i in range(len(X))]
```